Segmentation fault due to SIGBUS
I have written a code, to reverse the words in a string, and it works for some test cases. But the problem is for remaining cases, it returns segmentation fault. When I'm checking for errors, I found that the error is due to SIGBUS, bus error, not SIGSEGV. I've never encountered bus error sofar, and I couldn't understand the nature of problem. So, I request to find the error, or maybe correct my problem.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *);

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]",str);

    reverse(str);
    int len = strlen(str),i = 0,cn = 0;
    while(i <= len)
    {
        if(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0')
            cn++;
        else
        {
            int j = i - cn,k = i - 1;
            while(j != k)
            {
                char tm = str[j];
                str[j++] = str[k];
                str[k--] = tm;
            }
            cn = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n",str);
}

void reverse(char *str)
{
    int i = 0,len = strlen(str);
    while(i < len/2)
    {
        char tm = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len-1-i];
        str[len-1-i] = tm;
        i++;
    }
}


From your perspective both SIGBUS and SIGSEGV are pretty much the same. Your program is performing some memory violation, which can result in bus error as well as segmentation fault.

If you want to understand what is going on, you should print out the different indices (i, j, k) your program is using and see if some of them are going out of bounds.

Yes, I did that but the problem is, it works for some test cases, so, what's really happening is shady to me

take the case where it does not work and debug it.

str[j++] = str[k]; - runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'char [100]' - k is -1 here

Well, again I've done that, and the tricky part here, is that the place where the segmentation fault happens is not so much revealing to me, that's why I've posted it if someone has any idea bout it

@SanjaiS Look at my comment above yours. That's what happens if the user enters an even amount of characters.

If you printed the indices as suggested, you should have seen that -1..

@TedLyngmo Which tool is producing this output?

Use -g -fsanitize=address,undefined with gcc or clang to get the above output

you're a life saver, man!!!

And I hadn't saw any -1 there, that is why I've baffled about the problem, anyway, I'll try to sort it out

It will work when there are no spaces in the text supplied.

@cup Not really. It doesn't work for any even amount of characters while (i <= len) should be while (i < len)

Thats for counting the last word

@SanjaiS Yeah, there are multiple problems :)

If you changed your reverse function to take a length parameter too, you could reuse it when reversing the individual words.  Example

Strongly suggest a width limit in scanf to avoid an overflow. scanf("%99[^\n]",str); Also probably a good idea to initialize your str: char str[100] = "";

Your while loops are also better off as for loops.

You may wish to write a function to handle swapping chars in a string to avoid repeating that. void char_swap(char *a, char *b) { char tmp = *a; *a = *b; *b = tmp; }

@SanjaiS - To be nit-picking, Stack Overflow prefers that you add the solution as an answer, and not as a part of the question. You are very much allowed to answer your own questions. That also removes it from the "Unanswered questions" section.

@SanjaiS ... also, since you've made your reverse function take a length parameter, why are you not using it to reverse the individual words? Example
